# POST to /poll-notifications/ takes a loooong time immediately after application restart

Tags: apostrophe-cms

After each restart of my multisite project the application responds with 502 & 504 errors for about 2-3 minutes after the application comes back up.

Using [the --trace mode](https://pm2.io/doc/en/plus/guide/transaction-tracing) of PM2 I was able to track the issue down to apostrophe-notifications, and to the POST on /poll-notifications/.

The first request to the front end of one of these sites after deploy will take 2-3 minutes to respond successfully. The first attempt or two will timeout, responding with either a 502 or 504, and then generally the third will succeed and respond quickly.

The application is running on 3 processes and during this time CPU usage for at least one, but even all 3 processes at times will average 100%.

Any idea what could be at issue?

Comment: My guess is that you have not set up `minify: true` and, more importantly, are not running the `apostrophe:generation` command line task before these startups take place so they can all share a time-consuming asset build that has already been completed. The new notifications support in 2.75 didn't cause this, it just makes it obvious by making it visible to you that Apostrophe is taking 2-3 minutes to start up.

Comment: See https://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/intermediate/deployment.html for deployment best practices.

Comment: I've just done a test deploy logging the minify value (it's set to true) and my deploy script runs these commands just before restarting: `node app.js apostrophe:generation --site=dashboard`, `node app.js apostrophe:generation --all-sites`, so I believe I have my bases covered there.

Comment: Hmm, I want to help but I'm a little stuck at this point. We do use this same setup for our own multisite projects, and they don't exhibit this problem. Not sure what more to suggest without access to the environment in question.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but the long delay (2 minutes) also occurs when adding a user via the command line. I have added a bunch of console.logs with timestamps in the files in node_modules and gotten as far as: `self.addFromTask` does not fun for 1 minute 33 seconds, and then the query `self.apos.groups.find(req, { title: groupname }).toObject(function(err, group) {...` takes another 36 seconds. Does this provide any additional insight?

Comment: in index.js you can find `invokeModules`, which initializes all of the modules. You can log which one you've reached in that loop to learn more.

Comment: I have also observed that the poll-notifications http call takes some time to resolve. I have seen this through the network tab in the browser during development.